# Laravel remove iframe and img from html - str_limit

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I'm using `str_limit($data['last_post']['content'],800)` in blade for display first 800 characters from post. The problem is when user post video or image at the beginning of post. My question is: how to filter and remove `iframe`, `img` and display post first characters without this tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to simply use `$result = stripslashes($postDescription)` then use the below function to remove the iframe or image tags

```
function replacePostDesriptionUrls($postDesc = null) {
    $regex = '/<iframe.*?>(.*?)<\/iframe>/';

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 
        function($m){
            return escapeLink($m[0]);
        }, $postDesc);
}
```

Do the same for any tags you want to remove from your post description.

Comment: or you can take out all tag
`strip_tags(str_limit($data['last_post']['content'],800))`